# Approval process from one dev org to another dev org

Tags: deployment

Can anyone tell me how to deploy approval process from one dev org to another dev org?

Please its urgent..
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 3):

Providing you include the approval process type in your package.xml:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ...
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
    </types>
    ...
    <version>28.0</version>
</Package>
```

the approval processes can be extracted from an org into .approvalProcess files and deployed into another org using the Force.com IDE or the [Ant tools](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant.htm).

Approval processes can also be [included in change sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2013/05/approval-process-deployment%E2%80%94change-set-support-is-in-the-air.html).

Comment: :is there any blog or any document for this

Comment: @user3332076 See the link I added at the end about using change sets - that is probably easier if you do not use the Force.com IDE or the Ant tooling.

Comment: am using developer org

Comment: @user3332076 OK. I don't know of any good blogs but you should Google to see if you find one. A good start page for the Ant tooling is [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool).